# How could I save somewhere a short text with my Chrome Extension?

Tags: database, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am writing a Chrome extension which allows me to translate individual words on a website from one language to another. See my code below:

```
    function getword(info,tab) {

        console.log("Word " + info.selectionText + " was clicked.");
        chrome.tabs.create({ 

        //Open a dictionary website             
        url: "http://pl.bab.la/slownik/polski-angielski/" + info.selectionText,

        })


    }

    chrome.contextMenus.create({

        title: "Translate: %s", 
        contexts:["selection"], 
        onclick: getword,

    });
```

I'd like to keep the list of all requested words, so later, I can return to them and find out how many of them I have already rememberd. What approaches do you suggest?

- Should I just keep these words on a hard disk and if so, how to do it with JavaScript or HTML5?
- Should I use a database? This solution lets me keep there also number of searches for each word and have them ordered by count of requests
- (Other solution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use local storage for this. https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage.html

Comment: Chrome Storage is assigned to one website. I would like to have somwhere a list of every word I have ever serched.